# Maclaurin Series : $f(x) = 3\sin^2(x)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Use a Maclaurin series in this table to obtain the Maclaurin series for the given function.

$$f(x) = 3\sin^2(x)$$
[Hint: Use $\sin^2(x) = \frac{1}{2}\cdot(1-\cos(2x))$]

Series Sum from $0$ to $\infty$ = ?

Comment: Do you know series for cos(u)? then plug in $u=2x$ then subtract from 1 and then divide through by 2.

Comment: what is the $3$ doing there?

Comment: @abel Likely part of original question. So in my comment need to finalize by multiplying terms by $3.$

Comment: @coffeemath, i didn't mean it was meant for the op. i didnt think there was any need for the $3$ there.

Comment: @abel Your first comment asks what the $3$ is "doing there", and the only place I see that $3$ is in OP's definition of $f(x)$ in the title and displayed in post body. So I agree there's no need for it in the sense that the given function *could* have been defined without the multiplier $3.$ [As you can see I'm still a bit confused by your last response/comment...]

Answer (score 4):

HINT: if $$\cos(x)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}x^{2k},$$
then $$\cos(2x)=\sum_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}(2x)^{2k}$$
and $3\sin^2(x)=\frac{3}{2}\cdot\left(1-\cos(2x)\right)=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{3}{2}\cos(2x)$

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, consider that:

$f(x) = 3\sin^2(x) \implies f'(x) = 6\sin(x)\cos(x) = 3\sin(2x)$

The series for $f'(x)$, we can easily find:

$\displaystyle f'(x) = 3\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}2^{2k + 1}x^{2k + 1}}{(2k + 1)!}$

Thus $\displaystyle f(x) = \int f'(x) dx = \int 3\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}2^{2k + 1}x^{2k + 1}}{(2k + 1)!}$

> $f(x) \displaystyle = 3\cdot\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{k}2^{2k + 1}x^{2k + 2}}{(2k 
> + 2)!}$